# Why Android ScrollView calls onScrollChanged() when the height of its child is less than the screen?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` as its only child.
Lately I noticed that the method:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {}
```

is called even when the child height is less than the `ScrollView` height as you can see below:
[image]

this refers to my `ScrollView` and rl refers to the `RelativeLayout`.

Is this a normal behavior or am I missing something?

**Edit:** 
I'm constantly adding and removing views from the `RelativeLayout` so disabling the scroll/touch etc. each time doesn't seem like a good solution.

My current fix is to check whether the scroll actually changed anything, if not, I'm just ignoring it:

```
    // in case no actual scroll has occurred - just return.
    if (t == oldt && l == oldl) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behavior

If you want to stop ScrollView Scrolling then you must try this

```
scroll.setEnabled(false); 
scroll.setFocusable(false); 
scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Hope so this will work

Comment: Well this is a normal behavior of OS... If you try some HTC set it would not scroll. But in Samsung it would scroll.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, Thanks!